# What are the No Man's Sky technology levels?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've seen different "levels" of technology, such as Theta, Tau, Sigma, even an Omega.

The problem is I don't know which ones are better than the others. Is there a list of the different levels of technology from smallest to largest?

I'd like to be sure I'm upgrading my technology efficiently without accidentally downgrading.

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you. I did not see that one.